# config has a private access in GenericServlet

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying to upload an image (.jpg) file using common io in Servlet. While writing the following code ---

```
File savedFile = null;
savedFile = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/temp/" + fileName);
```

NetBeans is giving the error -- "config has a private access in GenericServlet".

Kindly help me out to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are already in a Servlet**
Remove the config in your code like so:
`savedFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/temp/" + fileName);`

**Note**
Please do not use this to upload files because the file you uploaded will be in you war file. This file will get lost once you deploy your application again. It is always better to save the file somewhere outside of your war file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are extending generic servlet or one of its sub classes. So In your class you can not directly access its `config` variable as it is declared privately.

so if you want to access `config` then use `getServletConfig()` method and if you want to access `context` then use `getServletContext() method